# Flutter Dart HTTP POST request body is empty on server side

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a Flutter tablet app. Once one input field is inputted, I am trying to send a post request to the server. Following is the method I am invoking for this:

```
    Future < http.Response > _postRequest() async {
    print(globals.novaCoord.toString() + ' XYZXYZXYZXYZXYZ');

    var url = globals.URL + 'api/nova_position';

    Map data = {
      'id_nova': '1',
      'position.x': '1',
      'position.y': '1',
      'position.z': '1',
      'position.pitch': '1',
      'position.yaw': '1',
      'position.roll': '1',
    };
    //encode Map to JSON
    var body = json.encode(data);

    http.Response response = await http.post(url,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: body
    );
    print("${response.statusCode}");
    print("${response.body}");
    return response;
  }
```

And on the NodeJs server side I have this:

```
app.post('/api/nova_position/', async (req,res) => {
    console.log("NOVA POSITION");
    console.log(req.body.id_nova);
    const id_nova = req.body.id_nova;
    const x = req.body.position.x;
    const y = req.body.position.y;
    const z = req.body.position.z;
    const pitch = req.body.position.pitch;
    const yaw = req.body.position.yaw;
    const roll = req.body.position.roll;

    const position = await db.db.create_position(id_nova,x,y,z,pitch,yaw,roll);
});
```

However, on the server-side, I am receiving an empty "body" for the request I sent and I receive the following error:

```
(node:23939) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

I need help at this point. I appreciate any help and guidance.

Comment: Are you calling `http.createServer` somewhere? Where's that code? Are you able to exercise your server with Postman?

Comment: Hi @RichardHeap I have a nodeJs server and even when I try with PostMan, I see that the server somehow, has an empty "body". I simply have to make sure of the server side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter POST json request body is empty/null on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73557840/flutter-post-json-request-body-is-empty-null-on-server-side)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to jsonEncode before pushing into Post request
Like

```
String bodyF = jsonEncode(body);
```

And i hope you will get your solution.

Comment: Yes you are correct. After I do the suggested fix, I have an updated code. I now am sure that I have an issue about the server. Received body from PostMan is empty too.

Comment: Empty body on server side may be caused by a mis-match of type between sending and receiving, which may be caused by headers. Plz see this answer for clarification!: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599552/14335655

Answer (score 12):

Sending `Map<String,dynamic>` with `http.post` won't send your data properly.

To solve this, change the content-type of the header to:

```dart
Map<String, String> customHeaders = {
...
"content-type": "application/json"
...
};
```

Then, you can use `http.post` as follows:

```dart
http.post(url, headers: customHeaders, body);
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution I have found was simply to add `Content-Length : x` to your header, with `x` being the size of your json body.