# Flutter POST json request body is empty/null on server side

Tags: json, .net, flutter, dart, http

I am sending a post request from my flutter to a localhost api. However, the body on the server side is always empty/null. Whereas, if I send the exact same request on postman everything works fine.

```
String json = jsonEncode(toCheck);
Map<String,String> headers = {
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "content-type": "application/json",
};

var response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(userPath + 'validateUser/'),
    headers:  headers,
    body: "{\"email\":\"david@hotmail.com\",\"username\":\"\",\"mobile_phone_number\":\"\",\"password\":\"david\"}");
print(response.statusCode);
if(response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok){
  return response.body as bool;
}
print(response.body.toString());
return false;
```

The status code is always 500 with the following error:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The value cannot be null"...

This error happens because the parameter "json" is null:

```
  [HttpPost]
  [Route("validateUser/", Name = "validadeUser")]
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ValidateUser([FromBody] string json)
  {
      //get the username and password to validate the user
      UserClient client = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserClient>(json); //error happens here because the string json is null
      //...
  }
```

However, when making the same exact request on postman, everything is okay:
[image: postman request]

The host on the android **emulator** app is the following:
**https://10.0.2.2:44304/api/user/validateUser/**

PS: looks like a duplicate of [Flutter POST request body is empty on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953966/flutter-post-request-body-is-empty-on-server-side) and [Flutter Dart HTTP POST request body is empty on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57823940/flutter-dart-http-post-request-body-is-empty-on-server-side) but none of those solutions have worked for me, therefore I posting a new question.

Comment: Plz tell me if my answer worked! Or otherwise what the problem was, if you solved it...

Comment: Sorry I have not yet tested the solution. I will try it now!

Comment: I believe this is an issue with your server, your Dart code works just fine: https://dartpad.dev/?id=78f77b37b800b01a57ea2362d08e9cd2 . It's possible that Postman is adding / modifying something that is making it work with your server but I have no idea what that would be. Try comparing what Postman sends to httpbin vs. what your Dart code sends.

Comment: This is good advice! Sending a curl would also have been a good idea. Because it turns out he DIDN'T send exactly the same in his Postman call... He must have left out `"content-type": "Application/json"` from the headers... See my answer!

Comment: @DavidAlmeida, plz see this chat qn, if you don't mind! https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247937/on-a-side-note

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to spot the error... but in the end, I did!

Your API takes a String argument from the request body:

```
  ValidateUser([FromBody] string json)
```

That may seem alright at first, since indeed, you are sending a json String as your request body. But the thing is that since you're also using these headers:

```
{
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "content-type": "application/json",
}
```

This bit: `"content-type": "application/json"` will translate your correctly formatted json String into an actual json Object! So when it reaches your API, it will no longer be a String, and so your API won't be able to receive it properly.

The solution would be to either remove the `"content-type": "application/json"` from your headers and keep the request body and the API function as they are, or to change the API to:

```
ValidateUser([FromBody] object json)
```

The latter is probably the most convenient, since you were going to parse it from json String to json Object anyway!

(With this API function, you COULD also remove your `"content-type": "application/json"` bit from the headers, and then send the request body like this:

```
  body: jsonDecode("{\"email\":\"david@hotmail.com\",\"username\":\"\",\"mobile_phone_number\":\"\",\"password\":\"david\"}"),
```

Or just not jsonEncode it in the first place... Just send it as an object. This will have the same effect as sending it as a json String with `"content-type": "application/json"` in the header.)

Btw, as a general rule, make sure you add lots of print and log statements in your code as you develop it! It will help you spot anything that didn't go quite as you had expected, along the way.  (That's how I spotted this.)

Comment: The thing is that on the emulator the 127.0.0.1 will reach the localhost of the emulator itself. I need to use 10.0.2.2 on the emulator. The 10.0.2.2 on the emulator will be translated to 127.0.0.1. The thing is that the request does reach my api. the only weird thing about it is that the body is always empty. I have tested now with the double / and it still does not work :/

Comment: There's gotta be something really simple we're missing... I suppose you tried the capital letter `Content-Type` as well?

Comment: Please show me exactly what the `userPath` String looks like! I'm thinking now there's something wrong in your Uri parsing that makes the body corrupted...

Comment: userPath is: https://10.0.2.2:44304/api/user/. userPath is correct, because the request does get to the api, the weird thing is that the body of the http method is empty! Yes I have tried Content-Type with capital letter as well :/ however to no avail

Comment: Why is there no "/" at the end of your userPath? And also not at the beginning of 'validateUser/'? It seems this part: `(userPath + 'validateUser/')` in your Uri.parse validates to `'10.0.2.2:44304/api/uservalidateUser/'` which is NOT correct! It is quite possible to reach your server while still having an error in the link, so long as the beginning of the link is correct...

Comment: Plz see my Edit above and tell me what happens.

Comment: And another edit..... 

Comment: I was confident that this time it might have worked but still no ugh xD. I have implemented both of edits and I even switched to http instead of https to see if something might change but still got the same result :/

Comment: DARNIT!!  Well, you've got the PostMan call to work!... So somewhere between that and your emulator call, the error happens... Compare everything! You can do it!!... Are you using the exact same headers?... I believe in you.

Comment: (Just for super clarity, you saw that you had spelt "validade" like that with a "d", yeah?)

Comment: What about the `print('Error in http.post: $e');`... Did it print anything? If so, what?

Comment: Edit 3 is now live... 

Comment: And Edit 4.......

Comment: Massive thanks Karolina, the content-type was translating my json string into an object therefore I had to change my api method signature to ([FromBody] object json). Thank you so such! It is working. For anyone that might have the same issue: Edit 4 was the one that solved my issue.

Comment:  I'm so happy now....  And you don't know how many times I wanted to click the "Headers" tab in that pic you posted, to check if you really used the same headers in the Postman call...!  But I couldn't, so I just trusted you....  Anyway, awesome. I will now re-write my answer for future readers.  Soon.

Answer (score 0):

Before sending the request to the server please encode your object to complete the body property of the request. Try this:

```
body: json.encode({\"email\":\"david@hotmail.com\",\"username\":\"\",\"mobile_phone_number\":\"\",\"password\":\"david\"})
```

Cheers.

Comment: It was correctly formatted. I checked. See my answer now, for the correct solution. 